# Would a target stunned by Stunning Strike still get their reaction to use against that attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, reactions

In the particular instance that raised the question, a target that was hit--and stunned--by a Monk's Stunning Strike then used their reaction for an ability (Banishing Rebuke) which banishes the attacker to another realm. Would they even have gotten the chance to use a reaction? Or would the stun have prevented it?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before (the exact features mentioned are different, but the question is still the same question).